# How can I make this two-column section stay on top of the background?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have this problem and I don't know why it won't let me put the cards on top of the background, they stay as if they were combined.

How can I fix this and position the cards on top of the background? I have already tried with the `z-index`, setting the background to 0, and all other containers to 1 or more and it does not come up.
Here's an image of what I have and how I want it.

What I have:

[image: Screenshot of two-column section]

What I want:

[image: Screenshot of two-column section overlapping parent section background]

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd guess for z-index, but, could you share this piece of code? It would be nice in a code sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: How do I send it to you? I have never used a codesandbox

Comment: How can I use it if I'm using Wordpress with elementor?

Comment: You can use floats to get content to hang out of the container like that.

Comment: What are the floats?

Comment: It appears to me that the columns in the "what I want" picture have a background color, whereas the columns in the "what I have" picture do not have a background color, allowing the other background to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

@Seis, if you are working with the editor like in the screenshot you posted, all you have to do is raise the z-index on each one of the columns.

[image]

Click on the column, then Advanced or Style, and put a higher number in the z-index field, as shown in my screenshot.

References:

https://web.dev/learn/css/z-index/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/